# Laravel Find the Query

Tags: laravel

I am beginner of laravel 
i have makes two table
1: **users**
2:**Survey**
user post the survey with some questions.
tell me the query how we can find the user who post the more survey then other users

Comment: show us what you tried. it should be really easy if you read the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're looking for Eloquent solution:

```
$user = User::withCount('surveys')->latest('surveys_count')->first();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the `latest` part? I would use order by for this kind of stuff. Just curious, not judging!